# how to update the JList in JScrollPane when I changed the cursor,Also,I'd want to know how to add video from http video API

Tags: java

When I started my project about a Dictionary from Chinese to English, I got some problems.First,
I used the addCaretListener method to realize that when I changed the cursor in wordLine,changed the context in JList and show the result.But here a problem comes,If I changed the cursor, the JList were clear,and not show anything.

Another problem is I want to invoke the http video API to realize the video play. As I add the video button and add the audio method to realize ,I failed.
I'll appreciate if you can solve them.

This is part of my code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;

import java.lang.Thread;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

import org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream;
import org.omg.CORBA.portable.OutputStream;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class DictionaryWindow extends JFrame{
    public  ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> meaningList = new ArrayList<>();
    private JButton searchBn=new JButton("搜索");
    private JTextField wordLine=new JTextField();
    private JButton addToNote=new JButton("添加入生词本");
    private JButton videoBn=new JButton();
    private JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane();
    private String waitForSearch;
    private String local="151310421";
    private JList list; 
    private int index=0;
    private int wordLocation;//查找想要找单词的序号
    private JTextField showMean=new JTextField();
    private String []str;
    private String []str1;
    //private String []str2;
    private TrieTree trie=new TrieTree();
    private Vector <String>v=new Vector <String>();
    private DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    private boolean wait=false;

    public DictionaryWindow()
    {
        toTrieTree();
    }

    public void dictionaryInit()
    {
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(600,500);

        str=wordList.toArray(new String[wordList.size()]);
        str1=meaningList.toArray(new String[meaningList.size()]);
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        {
            dlm.addElement(str[i]);
        }
        list=new JList(dlm);//v To str 
        scroll.setViewportView(list);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        searchBn.setBounds(200, 100, 60, 25);
        wordLine.setBounds(60, 100, 100, 25);
        addToNote.setBounds(60, 150, 200, 25);
        scroll.setBounds(300, 200, 100, 200);
        showMean.setBounds(300, 100, 200, 25);
        videoBn.setBounds(450,100,100,25);

        wordLine.addCaretListener(new CaretListener(){
            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e){
                trie.searchNextWords(wordLine.getText());
                String []str2=new String[]{};
                str2=null;
                str2=trie.wordL.toArray(new String[trie.wordL.size()]);
                //str=str2;
                //v.clear();
                //for(int i=0;i<str2.length;i++)
                    //v.add(str2[i]);`
                ((DefaultListModel)list.getModel()).removeAllElements();
                for(int i=0;i<str2.length;i++)
                {
                    dlm.addElement(str2[i]);
                }
                list.setModel(dlm);
                scroll.setViewportView(list);

                //JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(list);
                //scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
                //scroll.setBounds(300, 200, 100, 200);
                //add(scroll);
            }
        });
        addToNote.addActionListener(e->{
            String writeFilePath = local + ".txt";
            try {
                String note = wordLine.getText() + "    " + showMean.getText();
                Files.write(Paths.get(writeFilePath), Arrays.asList(note), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.err.println("File Writing error\n" + e);
            }
        });
        videoBn.addActionListener(e->{

                class sound extends Applet{
                    AudioClip loopClip;
                    public void init()
                    {
                        String word=wordLine.getText();
                        String httpVideo="http://dict.youdao.com/dictvoice?type=1&audio="+word;
                            try {
                                loopClip=getAudioClip(new URL(httpVideo));
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }
                    public sound(){
                        init();
                        loopClip.play();
                    }
                }
            sound s=new sound();
        });
        searchBn.addActionListener(e->{
            wordLocation=0;
            waitForSearch=wordLine.getText();
            while(!waitForSearch.equals(str[wordLocation]))
            {
                wordLocation++;
            }
            showMean.setText(str1[wordLocation]);
        });

        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                if(e.getClickCount()==2)
                    twoClick(list.getSelectedValue());
            }

            private void twoClick(Object selectedValue) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                wordLine.setText((String) selectedValue);
            }
        });


        Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 2, 2, Color.RED);
        showMean.setBorder(border);
        showMean.setEditable(false);

        this.add(searchBn);
        this.add(wordLine);
        this.add(addToNote);
        this.add(scroll);
        this.add(showMean);
        this.add(videoBn);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }

   /* class doubleClick extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.getClickCount() ==2) {
                wordLine.setText((JList)e.getSource());
            }
        }
    }*/


    public void toTrieTree()
    {
        int i=0;
        while(i<wordList.size())
        {
            trie.insert(str[i],str1[i]);
            dlm.addElement(str[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please one post for each problem

Comment: There is far to much code here. Please compress to an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).